# Can't connect to mysql after ipconfg /release

Tags: windows, networking, mysql

I am not able to connect to mysql server local and remote and it throws the below error. Platform on windows.

```
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading authorization packet', system error: 2
```

I suspect this issue started eversince i did a ipconfig /release and renew. 
This may be due to a networking issue.

Can someone guide me.

Comment: Is this during mysql connect or during query? take a look on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-lost-connection.html it is similar case try to tune **net_read_timeout**

Comment: @asktyagi It is during connect. Tried via mysql workbench and command line. I am not able to connect the server.

Comment: Why did you need to release/renew?

Comment: some internet issues .